# GUI tkinter / My main window is covering my created toplavel

Tags: tkinter

Well I'm creating app with tkinter, and I fix myself with this question:

I have the code apparently does not have a problem, but the main window overlaps the toplavel, note: I already tried to use focus (all possible).
here is the code:

```
 from tkinter import *
 root = Tk()
 root.title("Tecl De Des")
 root.geometry("800x600+275+50")
 winfo_screen_X = root.winfo_screenwidth()
 winfo_screen_Y = root.winfo_screenheight()
 class Teclado(object):
     def __init__(self,root):
         self.toplvl = Toplevel(root)
         self.toplvl.geometry("250x200+{}+{}".format(winfo_screen_X//2 - 150, winfo_screen_Y//2 -100))
         self.toplvl.mainloop()
 class rom():
     pass
 Teclado(root)
 root.mainloop()
```

Comment: could you provide a ss ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the `toplevel` window on top of its parent window, you can use

```
self.toplvl.transient(root)
```

inside `__init__()` of `Teclado` class.

Also you don't need to call `self.toplvl.mainloop()`.